# How to stretch an iOS UISlider

Tags: ios, uislider, stretch

I want to use the standard iOS slider in my application, but wanted it to be a bit stretched so it doesn't "disappear" under my finger... neither google or the books informed me about this.. Is is possible? thks!

Comment: And where is the original thumb png so i can edit it? thk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a custom thumb image then, using `setThumbImage:forState:`

Comment: thks @Irene, looking for it right now, but need to access the original thumb png to edit it and get it bigger..

Comment: i got hold to a png from the web. thks Irene :)